# Displaying similarities and differences between 2 rasters in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, random-forest, r-raster

I'm trying to create a raster that shows where a random forest prediction and neural network prediction agree and disagree. Each raster is a prediction of 6 land classes and I want to create a new raster that is a comparison between the two where cells of agreed-upon predictions are green and cells of disagreeing predictions are red.

Here is my code for the two prediction methods and their rasters:

```
trainD <- dataAll[dataAll$sampleType == "train",]
validD <- dataAll[dataAll$sampleType == "valid",]

# Random Forest
# use 'Caret' package to find the optimal parameter settings
tc <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                   number = 10, # number 10 fold
                   repeats = 10) # number of repeats
rf.grid <- expand.grid(mtry=1:sqrt(9)) # use 9 bc we have 9 bands

# train the random forest model to the Sentinel-2 data through Caret
trainD <- na.omit(trainD) #omit points in cloud areas from training  points
rf_model <- caret::train(x = trainD[,c(5:13)],  #digital number data
                         y = as.factor(trainD$landcID),  
                         method = "rf",  
                         metric="Accuracy",  
                         trainControl = tc,  #use parameter tuning 
                         tuneGrid = rf.grid)  #parameter tuning grid
#check output
rf_model

# Change name in raster stack to match training data
names(allbandsCloudf) <- c("B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B11","B12")
# Apply the random forest model to the Sentinel-2 data
rf_prediction <- raster::predict(allbandsCloudf, model=rf_model)
#view predictions
plot(rf_prediction)
# landcover class names
landclass

# set up categorical colors for each class using hex codes
landclass$cols <-c("#a6d854","#8da0cb","#66c2a5",
                   "#fc8d62","#ffffb3","#ffd92f")
# make plot and hide legend
plot(rf_prediction, #random forest prediction
     breaks=seq(0,6), #number of landclasses
     col=landclass$cols , 
     legend=FALSE, axes=FALSE) #hide legend


# Neural Networks
# set up grid
nnet.grid <- expand.grid(size = seq(from = 16, to = 28, by = 2), 
                         decay = seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.6, by = 0.1))
# train the model
nnet_model <- caret::train(x = trainD[,c(5:13)], 
                           y = as.factor(trainD$landcID),
                           method = "nnet", 
                           metric= "Accuracy", 
                           trainControl = tc, 
                           tuneGrid = nnet.grid,
                           trace=FALSE)
# view the training summary
nnet_model
# apply the neural network model to the Sentinel-2 data
nnet_prediction <- raster::predict(allbandsCloudf, model=nnet_model)
# make plot and hide legend
plot(nnet_prediction, #plot the neural network predictions
     breaks=seq(0,6), #number of landclasses
     col=landclass$cols ,
     legend=FALSE) #hide the legend
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @tpants12, this community is a Question an Answer community. In this post isn't clear what are your question. 
Could you explicit yours question?
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What *exactly* is your issue and your *question*?

Comment: @vpz and desertnaut Thank you! You two are absolutely right that I totally forgot to directly ask my question. Rookie mistake! My question was "does anyone have any suggestions for how to accomplish creating the new raster using the two prediction rasters?" Luckily, I was able to figure out a solution to my own question so I posted an answer in case anyone else was trying to solve a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer to my own question! I just used overlay and then set the colors to what I wanted and added a legend.

Here's the code if anyone is trying to solve a similar problem:

```
diff <- overlay(rf_prediction, nnet_prediction, fun=function(a,b) return(a==b))
plot(diff,
     col=c('#FFE4E1','#228B22'),
     legend=FALSE,
     axes=FALSE)
legend("left", legend=c("Agree", "Disagree"),
       col=c("#228B22", "#FFE4E1"), pch = 15, cex=0.8)
```